# Counting amount of values in joined table with multiple corresponding entries

Tags: sql

Trying to figure out the following SQL command:

You have 2 tables, mainTable and subTable. mainTable consists of a pkmainTable column and subTable consists of pksubTable, fkmainTable, bitVal1, bitVal2

I want to figure out every entry in mainTable, where in all the corresponding (-> m.pkmainTable = s.fkmainTable) subTable entries none have (bitVal1 = true OR bitVal2 = true)

My current attempt (in Pseudo-SQL Code, it doesn't work):

```
SELECT *
FROM mainTable as m
    INNER JOIN subTable as s ON m.pkmainTable = s.fkmainTable
WHERE SUM(CASE WHEN s.bitVal1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
   OR SUM(CASE WHEN s.bitVal2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

### Example tables:

mainTable

```
pkmainTable<br>
1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
```

subTable

```
pksubTable | fkmainTable | bitVal1 | bitVal2<br>
1          | 1           | 1       | 1<br>
2          | 1           | 0       | 0<br>
3          | 1           | 0       | 1<br>
4          | 2           | 0       | 0<br>
5          | 2           | 0       | 1<br>
6          | 3           | 0       | 0<br>
7          | 3           | 1       | 0<br>
8          | 3           | 0       | 1<br>
9          | 4           | 0       | 0<br>
```

The result should give back the entries in mainTable where pkmainTable = 2 or 4

Comment: Show us the expected result as formatted text as well!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For conditions on aggregate functions (SUM, COUNT, etc.) you need to use HAVING clause. But in this case it will just overcomplicate things, the NOT EXISTS function should work just fine - it returns true if the subquery returns zero rows. For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mainTable as m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
FROM subTable as s
WHERE m.pkmainTable = s.fkmainTable
AND (s.bitVal1 = 1  OR s.bitVal2 = 1))
```

---

And here is how you do it with aggregate function:

```
SELECT m.pkmainTable FROM mainTable as m
INNER JOIN subTable as s ON m.pkmainTable = s.fkmainTable
GROUP by m.pkmainTable
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN s.bitVal1 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0 
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN s.bitVal2 = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding Mikhail's technically correct answer, your specification states that the result set should contain rows in mainTable where **none** of the related rows in subTable have (bitVal1 = 1 OR bitVal2 = 1).

This disagrees with your test data and sample output. For mainTable value of 2 there are two rows in subtable, one of which contains bitVal2 = 1 thereby disqualifying it from your sample output.

Apart from that I was about to suggest the NOT EXISTS solution mentioned by Mikhail, who got there first while I was debugging your screwy test case.

```
SELECT * FROM mainTable
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT fkMainTable FROM subTable 
WHERE fkMainTable = pkMainTable AND (bitVal1 = 1 OR bitVal2 = 1));
```